# WshShortcut set shell size

Tags: vbscript

i create desktop shortcuts with vbscript.

With the WindowsStyle property i can determine if shell starts minimized, maximized or last set size. But the shell's i created have a maximum width of 80 characters.

Is there a way to set this to a bigger value? Setting font size and type would be interessing too.

```
set oMyShortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\Shortcut 

Script.lnk")oMyShortcut.WindowStyle = 4
oMyShortcut.TargetPath = "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"
oMyShortCut.Arguments= "/K """ & strProjectHome & "\" & strSetenvPath & """"
oMyShortCut.WorkingDirectory= strProjectHome
oMyShortcut.IconLocation = "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"
oMyShortcut.Description = "Shell for project " + strProjectName + " in directory " + strDirname +". This shortcut has been created automatically."
oMyShortCut.Save
```

regards
Andreas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can give the mode parameters like this, i commented out your parameters but you can add them also.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
set oMyShortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\ShortcutScript.lnk")
oMyShortcut.WindowStyle = 4
oMyShortcut.TargetPath = "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"
'oMyShortCut.Arguments= "/K """ & strProjectHome & "\" & strSetenvPath & """"
oMyShortCut.Arguments= "/K mode con:cols=150 lines=40"
oMyShortCut.WorkingDirectory= strProjectHome
oMyShortcut.IconLocation = "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"
oMyShortcut.Description = "Shell for project " + strProjectName + " in directory " + strDirname +". This shortcut has been created automatically."
oMyShortCut.Save
```

This gives a nice wide console screen when you double click the shortcut

The only way i found to change the font is by manually changing it once on a shortcut and then use that as a template, copy it and then change the other parameters. Changing a shortcus is the same way as opening it, so

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
set oMyShortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\ShortcutScript.lnk")
oMyShortCut.Arguments= "/K mode con:cols=80 lines=40"
oMyShortCut.Save
```

sets our shortcutfile from above in 80 cols instead of the original 120 cols.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first bounty. I thought accepting your answer is enough. Did you receive the bonus?